# Compression of gaussian mixtures

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution

Is there a general way of fitting a gaussian mixture with $m$ components with a gaussian mixture with $n \ll m$ components, short of generating samples and redoing a full fit?  I expect a lot of components to be "naturally" merge-able, i.e. with "close" means and variances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11634-010-0058-3) might be something in that direction.

I hope this helps.

(can't add this as a comment as I don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: Please add this as a comment, not as an answer. An answer should contain a brief summary of the paper or the idea at least.

Comment: @Mayou36, unfortunately I can't as I don't have enough points.

Comment: okey then. May add some comments to what the paper is about? Or a short summary?